How to solve the issue Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1) after sudo apt --fix-broken install
After running command
sudo apt --fix-broken install

Getting the following issue
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  zfsutils-linux
Suggested packages:
  nfs-kernel-server
The following packages will be upgraded:
  zfsutils-linux
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 9 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/354 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 196274 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../zfsutils-linux_0.8.3-1ubuntu12.18_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking zfsutils-linux (0.8.3-1ubuntu12.18) over (0.8.3-1ubuntu12.17) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/zfsutils-linux_0.8.3-1ubuntu12.18_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 unable to create '/etc/sudoers.d/zfs.dpkg-new' (while processing './etc/sudoers.d/zfs'): Operation not permitted
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
zfs-import-scan.service is a disabled or a static unit, not starting it.
zfs-import-scan.service is a disabled or a static unit, not starting it.
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/zfsutils-linux_0.8.3-1ubuntu12.18_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Basically Im trying to install following packages
1)xinetd tftpd
2)nfs-kernel-server
3)minicom
4)build-essential
5)libncurses5-dev
6)autoconf
7)automake
8)dos2unix
9)screen
10)lrzsz
11)lzop
12)flex
13)libssl-dev
14u-boot-tools
